# sibbi's stash key not opening stash in quest "promises to keep"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I am doing the quest "promises to keep" and i persuaded sibbi to give me the key to his stash.

I went to the Black Briar brewing. Went to the basement and at the bottom of the stairs is the chest. I have the key in my inventory but it will not allow me to open the chest. Keeps saying that a key is required.

Bug? Am i doing something wrong? Suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the [Black briar lodge](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Briar_Lodge) you are in [Black briar meadery](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Black-Briar_Meadery).

There will be two men outside in front of the lodge, an archer and a swordsman. You can either fight them and enter through the front or sneak around and open the basement door on the West side of the house.

Once downstairs, there will be a barrel in the back with the papers in a strongbox. The papers may also be found on one of the tables.

More about the quest [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Promises_to_Keep).

Comment: Oops, lol. Where do i get the key for the Black Briar brewery chest? I have not found it yet. Thanks!

Comment: When you complete this quest sibbi will give you another key for the chest in brewery.